# How to drop records in a data frame where data is missing in exactly the desired columns?

Tags: python, pandas

In [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), it is shown that using `subset` will drop rows where if a cell in any of the listed columns has missing data. However, I want to drop data only if there is missing data in ALL the columns I list (not to be confused with all the columns I have in my data frame). So to be extra clear:

```
    born       name              first_appearance
0 1940-04-25 Batman              1945-09-01
1   NaT      Captain America     1960-02-03
2   NaT      Pikachu              NaT
```

I would only want to drop the last record. Where all dates are of the timestamp type.

Comment: The very next argument in the same docs you link is `how`...

Comment: `df.dropna(subset=['born','first_appearance'],axis=0,thresh =1)
`

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, you can add thresh and axis parameters:

```
df.dropna(subset=['born', 'first_appearance'],axis=0, thresh=1)
```